# Missing operation system and can't enter bios

Tags: windows, boot, bios

I tried to load my default settings from the Bios.

But when i did and i restarted i get the message:

```
Missing operation system
```

Whenever i try to restart i cannot enter the bios and change the `boot setup`.

So what can i do?

Also i do not have my windows cd lying around but the operation system should still be installed on the computer.

**Update**:

Okay i found my windows 7 cd.

However i cannot change boot so i cant make it boot from the disc

Comment: "change boot"? You mean you can't change boot order? Or you can't enter BIOS? Or you can't boot the disk? Also, no need to reinstall system after BIOS setting reset. You can configure it to boot up again. Ofcourse, if you are not willing to re/install the Windows.

Comment: @LittleHelper i can't change boot nor can i enter the bios using del and F2 or F12

Comment: Why can't you enter BIOS? Is the PC not starting? Does it not POST? Does it give you an error when you try? What make/model of PC/mobo are you using?

Comment: would that be operating system not operation. typo? It's important to get the right quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually many different ways to enter the BIOS, and which one is correct to use completely depends on your particular PC's motherboard.

Rather than trying and guessing, like I have to do in this answer, you could just look up on Google `"(PC model here) how to enter BIOS"` and you'd probably get a good step-by-step guide.

---

On the first screen that appears there may something somewhere which indicates a button to press to enter the BIOS. Here are some common ways the computer tells you which button to press *(within the first couple seconds of turning it on)*

- Press [key] to enter setup
- Setup: [key]
- Enter BIOS by pressing [key]
- Press [key] to enter BIOS setup
- Press [key] to access BIOS
- Press [key] to access system configuration

This is most likely...

- the `Esc` key
- A Function key, (`F1`, `F2`, `F8`, `F10`, `F12`)
- the `Delete` key

[Here is a link](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_pc.htm) which lists Bios Access keys for popular computer systems. The most common seem to be `F1`, `F2`, `Esc` and `Delete`. Note that you may need to press the key repeatedly.

Another method I've come across, though I have no idea if this works for any PC:
`Restart the system. As soon as the screen goes blank. Hold down several keys at once. The intent is to cause a keyboard error to force access to the BIOS.`

---

You are receiving an error message about a lack of an operating system, so I am assuming your BIOS is fine - since that means you are Passing POST and it is trying to load an operating system - though the sudden disappearance of your operating system means your hard drive may be damaged or corrupted.

However, if the computer were to do *nothing* when turning it on - the problem would either be with your power supply or your motherboard. Make sure your outlet (and power adapter, if applicable) are working and check connections of the power supply inside the pc if you have a desktop.

If it was powering on and not passing POST (usually indicated by messages or multiple beeps) - there is some piece of hardware either missing or not set up correctly.